# How to hide displaying other videos in dailymotion?

Tags: android, video, android-webview, android-videoview, dailymotion-api

Hi I am using dailymotion api to display list of videos in listview and clicking on particular video, I am passing id to play the particular video in [Dailymotion videoview](https://github.com/dailymotion/dailymotion-sdk-android/blob/master/SampleApp/src/main/java/com/dailymotion/websdksample/SampleActivity.java) by refering this.

```
  mVideoView = ((DMWebVideoView) findViewById(R.id.dmWebVideoView));
    mVideoView.setVideoId("x26hv6c"); // here i am passing id from listview through intent.
    mVideoView.setAutoPlay(true);
```

But problem is after the video completed,  it is displaying other list of videos which I never added at all. How to avoid displaying that?

Here is screenshot where it start displaying list of other videos after completion of previous video.

How to overcome this? Because on clicking of particular video, it start to display dailymotion header and goes out of control. You can refer screenshot 2.

[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called the endscreen. When a video is displayed, Dailymotion offers you to watch some related videos. You can disable this by passing the `endscreen-enable` player parameter (https://developer.dailymotion.com/player#player-parameters): it is a boolean indicating whether to enable the end screen or not. If you pass false, then you won't have those related videos.